# Deploying a pytorch model in java

Tags: java, pytorch

I have a pytorch model trained and saved and now I want to use it in a java (not android) environment in windows os (since I'm using some library only available in java), Is it possible? I couldn't find a straight answer in the pytorch docs, and when clicking java api docs the link is broken.

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://github.com/pytorch/java-demo)? Also, note that the question is considered off-topic, since it is specifically asking for recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, seems like windows is not supported.

Comment: The JavaCPP Presets for PyTorch work on Windows and you get access to pretty much all of the C++ API: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/pytorch

Answer (score 2):

@Gilad, You can do this with Deep Java Library (djl.ai). Check out: https://github.com/awslabs/djl/tree/master/pytorch/pytorch-engine

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @amarchin here's worked one: https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, you can do it with [Deep Java Library](https://github.com/awslabs/djl/tree/master/pytorch/pytorch-engine)

However, please note that for this to work, you need to convert your pytorch model into a torchscript model.

Here is one way of doing it. https://djl.ai/docs/pytorch/how_to_convert_your_model_to_torchscript.html